# How to convert image path to http url in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, rest

My Main domain is http://172.27.88.111. I have a relative path to a image file like Media/myimg.jpg

I need to convert this path into a full URL with the help of REST API in asp.net.

I want the output for the image path in POSTMAN something like

http://172.17.88.111/Media/myimg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Using a LINQPad script as an example, here are 3 examples - but the use of the 'Uri' class is generally the best way to advocate:

```
void Main()
{
    var baseUrlStr = @"http://172.27.88.111";
    var relUrlStr = @"/Media/myimg.jpg";

    // # 1
    var baseUri = new Uri(baseUrlStr);
    var relUri = new Uri(relUrlStr, UriKind.Relative);

    var absUri = new Uri(baseUri, relUri);

    Console.WriteLine(absUri);

    // # 2
    Console.WriteLine($"{baseUrlStr}{relUrlStr}");

    // # 3
    Console.WriteLine(baseUrlStr + relUrlStr);
}
```

This should give the following output:

```
http://172.27.88.111/Media/myimg.jpg 
http://172.27.88.111/Media/myimg.jpg
http://172.27.88.111/Media/myimg.jpg
```